# Why is std::erase(std::erase_if) not a template in <algorithm> that works on any container?

Tags: c++, stl, c++20, c++-concepts

`std::erase(_if)` is a nice addition to C++20(finally I can forget about obnoxious erase-remove idiom), but one thing is weird:
it is not a generic algorithm in a sense that it only works for std:: containers, e.g. it can not operate on boost vector.

```
    #include<string>

    #include<vector>

    #include<boost/container/vector.hpp>

    int main() {
        std::string str = " Hello World  !";
        std::erase(str, ' '); // :)
        boost::container::vector<int> vi{1,2};
        std::erase(vi, 2); // :(
    }
```

My best guess is that the algorithm was in experimental long before concepts were voted in standard so it was a lot of work to rework it, or that there was fear that concept for it could not be specified properly(i.e. it would work incorrectly on some user defined types with funky semantics).

So: my question is why is this not a generic algorithm in  with some Concept(or enable_if) requirements/dispatching(e.g. for map/set)?

Comment: Working this out in my head, I can think of only vector and list containers as being able to employ the same general logic for this; not even that, I can think of one additional optimization for a vector that wouldn't apply to list. Given that, I don't really see what the generic algorithm would even be, instead of simply implementing the appropriate overloads for each individual container. Starting point to ask yourself: how would a template know that `erase()` on a vector would invalidate the iterators its using to iterate over the container, but not for a list or associative containers?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is answered in the original proposal, [N4009](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4009.htm):

> Q10. Instead of overloading erase_if() for each container, should you
>   provide a single erase_if(Container&, Predicate) function template
>   that's specified to do the right thing for each container?
>
> A10. Such a general function template could be given user-defined
>   containers. There aren't any "container traits", so it's impossible to
>   determine whether a user-defined container is vector-like, list-like,
>   map-like, or something else. User-defined containers could simply be
>   rejected, but then the general function template wouldn't be doing
>   anything differently than the set of specific overloads being proposed
>   here.  Note that an author of a user-defined container can overload
>   erase_if() for their container in their namespace.

TL;DR: because there's no way to write such "Concept(or enable_if) requirements/dispatching".

Comment: to be fair if the container has a random access iterator tags on .begin(), .end() you could assume implementation can be same as for vector,  but I agree that for map/list it is very hard